# Redshift keeps changing back to 6500K after a few seconds

Tags: 20.04, redshift

I restarted my computer today and suddenly redshift wasnt activating on boot so I used the command redshift -O 3500 to try and set it manually but when I hit enter it changed to 3500K for a few seconds and then changed back to 6500K. I tried uninstalling redshift and redshift-gtk, also purging their files, checking task manager to see if there was any secondary instance of redshift running, restarting my laptop and nothing seems to work. Any suggestions?

Edit: I'm trying to use sct but I get the same problem.

Comment: I have found that you can't run both `redshift` and `redshift-gtk` at the same time unless `redshift` is set for automatic because there is no settings in `redshift-gtk` for you to manually set the color.  I would recommend stopping `redshift-gtk` or get rid of it as it conflicts with manually setting `redshift`.

Comment: @Terrance I tried running each one individually also. But now i tried to use sct to change color temps and I get the same problem (i have both redshift and redshift-gtk uninstalled and purged atm).

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?  Also, what is the output of `ps -ef | grep redshift`?

Comment: @Terrance 20.04. `louis       8979    5853  0 11:01 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/redshift-gtk
louis       9011    8979  0 11:01 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/redshift -v
louis      12164   11915  0 11:25 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto redshift`

Comment: @Terrance Ill try restarting again to see if it makes any difference

Comment: Yep, redshift was still running there.  Even after uninstalling it I have seen it hang on until it is killed.

Comment: @Terrance Apparently so! Now after the restart, sct works just fine. Redshift is a sticky son a gun haha. Thanks for the help, Terrance. Have a good one!

Comment: No problem!  You can use `redshift` or `redshift-gtk` but don't use both at the same time.  If `sct` is doing what you need it to do, go with that.  Have a good one too!  =)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, found a solution to this problem in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
Just right click on the system tray of Redshift and exit if it is already open.

Then open a terminal (ctrl+alt+T) and type the command for changing the  temperature manually.

```
redshift -O 3700
```